# Jackson serialize GeoJsonPoint as latitude / longitude

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class Post that looks like this:

```
@Document(collection = "Posts")
@Data
public class Post {

    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    @NonNull private String userId;
    @NonNull private String firstName;
    @NonNull private String lastName;
    private String postText;
    private String postImageUri;
    @NonNull private String googlePlaceId;
    @NonNull private String googlePlaceName;
    @NonNull private GeoJsonPoint location;

    @JsonCreator
    public Post(@JsonProperty("userId") String userId,
                @JsonProperty("firstName")String firstName,
                @JsonProperty("lastName")String lastName,
                @JsonProperty("postText") String postText,
                @JsonProperty("postImageUri") String postImageUri,
                @JsonProperty("googlePlaceId") String googlePlaceId,
                @JsonProperty("googlePlaceName") String googlePlaceName,
                @JsonProperty("latitude") long latitude,
                @JsonProperty("longitude") long longitude) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.postText = postText;
        this.postImageUri = postImageUri;
        this.googlePlaceId = googlePlaceId;
        this.googlePlaceName = googlePlaceName;
        this.location = new GeoJsonPoint(longitude, latitude);
    }

}
```

This class is used by the Mongo-reactive-driver to be stored in a Mongo db database. The GeoJsonPoint is a special type that is stored, so I don't want to store latitude and longitude fields separately.

Basically my code works well. Using Spring boot:

```
@PostMapping("")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Post>> savePost(@RequestBody final Post post) {
    // Fire and forgat
    ablyService.publishPost(post.getGooglePlaceId(), post);
    return postRepo.save(post)
            .map(savedPost -> new ResponseEntity<>(savedPost, HttpStatus.CREATED));
}
```

My problem is when I write the integration test. What I want to do:

```
@Test
public void createPostTest() {
    Post post = new Post("someUserId", "Kim", "Gysen",
            "Some text", "http://zwoop.be/imagenr",
            "googlePlaceId", "googlePlaceName", 50, 50);

    webTestClient.post().uri(BASE_URI)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .body(Mono.just(post), Post.class)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isCreated()
            .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$._id").isNotEmpty()
            .jsonPath("$.userId").isEqualTo(post.getUserId())
            .jsonPath("$.firstName").isEqualTo(post.getFirstName())
            .jsonPath("$.lastName").isEqualTo(post.getLastName())
            .jsonPath("$.postText").isEqualTo(post.getPostText())
            .jsonPath("$.postImageUri").isEqualTo(post.getPostImageUri())
            .jsonPath("$.location.x").isEqualTo(post.getLocation().getX())
            .jsonPath("$.location.y").isEqualTo(post.getLocation().getY());
}
```

The error I get is:

> org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error:
>   [simple type, class
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint]; nested
>   exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of
>   `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint` (no Creators,
>   like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value
>   (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

What I want is to serialize the object with "latitude" and "longitude" json fields in the test, while keeping the rest of my implementation logic working as is. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Oh well. Just fixed it by changing the api to accept a custom 'location' field and writing a jackson serializer:

```
@Document(collection = "Posts")
@Data
public class Post {

    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    @NonNull private String userId;
    @NonNull private String firstName;
    @NonNull private String lastName;
    private String postText;
    private String postImageUri;
    @NonNull private String googlePlaceId;
    @NonNull private String googlePlaceName;
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocationToLatLngSerializer.class)
    @NonNull private GeoJsonPoint location;

    @JsonCreator
    public Post(@JsonProperty("userId") String userId,
                @JsonProperty("firstName")String firstName,
                @JsonProperty("lastName")String lastName,
                @JsonProperty("postText") String postText,
                @JsonProperty("postImageUri") String postImageUri,
                @JsonProperty("googlePlaceId") String googlePlaceId,
                @JsonProperty("googlePlaceName") String googlePlaceName,
                @JsonProperty("location") Geolocation location) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.postText = postText;
        this.postImageUri = postImageUri;
        this.googlePlaceId = googlePlaceId;
        this.googlePlaceName = googlePlaceName;
        this.location = new GeoJsonPoint(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
    }

    static class LocationToLatLngSerializer extends JsonSerializer<GeoJsonPoint> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(GeoJsonPoint value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeNumberField("latitude", value.getX());
            gen.writeNumberField("longitude", value.getY());
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```